# What does removing the first principal component from data signify?

Tags: pca, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

The first principal component is the axis along which the data varies the most. So, what happens if I remove that while retaining all the remaining components? I am guessing that the data kind of coalesces together, but I am not sure.

Comment: Remove it from what?

Comment: You can always ignore the first PC, meaning simply not use it. Then you'll be focusing on whatever the others tell you. A fairly common example is that you have various  measures with dimension length all fed into a PCA. Then the first PC is sometimes interpretable as an overall summary of size and the others convey information on what is left, optimistically shape and pessimistically measurement error.

Comment: In classic, linear PCA you can and may remove any, not only first, PC not only conceptually but also actually. This amounts to removing the corresponding term from the linear combination of components as variable predictors.

Comment: If you are thinking about factor analysis (psychometrics, subjective opinions) and not just PCA (objective facts), you might look into Terence (T. J. G.) Tracey's work on partialing out the first unrotated factor as a "general factor" attributable to bias, e.g., to 
 social desirability or common method bias.

Comment: @mkt I mean if I discarded the first PC, while retaining all the remaining ones, what could that mean intuitively? Will the data points plotted on the new axes now look more uniform?

Comment: @NickCox So, if I have 10 features and I remove the first PC, would the datapoints now become more scattered (with the new axes) or more uniform?

Comment: @ttnphns Can you please explain it intuititvely? I am not from math or statistics, and I only use them sparingly.

Comment: @rolando2 Thank you, but I am looking for just PCA.

Comment: More scattered or more uniform: How are you measuring or judging either? In what space?

Comment: Removing a dimension from a data cloud, such as removing 1st PC of it, amounts to projecting data points onto the (hyper)plane perpendicular to the axis of that dimension. Imagine as example that your data is spheroid in 3D space. The PC1 is the spheroids main axis. Removing it is the projecting onto the plane which that axis pierces at 90 degree angle. Then, you are left with spherical data cloud lying in that plane.

Comment: Your question 'Will the data points plotted on the new axes now look more uniform'? is a puzzling one. By definition, what you are doing is ignoring (/removing) the axis of most variance in the data. Whether that is a good or a bad idea depends on your data and your question. If you are more specific about your problem, then you might get answers that can explain things more intuitively.

Answer (score 5):

Removing a dimension from a data cloud, such as removing 1st PC of it, amounts to projecting data points onto the (hyper)plane perpendicular to the axis of that dimension. Imagine as example that your data is spheroid in 3D space. The PC1 is the spheroids main axis. Removing it is the projecting onto the plane which that axis pierces at 90 degree angle. Then, you are left with spherical data cloud lying in that plane.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @ttnphns as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.